# 5 consecutive heads in 25 coin tosses with linearity of expectation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

I am reasoning around the linearity of expectation.

If for example, I want to know the expected number of a pair HH in 25 tosses (note that HHH has 2 possible HH pairs) I could use linearity of expectation and say that:

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}(H) &= 0.5 \\
\mathbb{P}\left(H^2\right) = 0.5*0.5 = 0.25
\end{split}
$$

Since I have 24 possible HH pairs in 25 tosses, then the expected number of HH pairs is

$$\mathbb{E}[25]=24*0.25 = 6$$

Now if I would like to know the expected value of seeing 5 consecutive heads in 25 tosses, it should simply be:

1. in 25 tosses there are 21 possible 5-head sequences.
2. $P(H^5)=0.5^5 = \frac{1}{32}$

$E[25] =  \frac{21}{32} \approx 0.66$ is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  Linearity of expectation is *very* powerful.  That really is all there is to it here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Unclear if you have interpreted the problem as the OP (i.e. original poster) intended.  If OP is asking for the expected number of occurrences of $5$ consecutive heads in the series of coin flips, then I agree.  However, the OP may instead have intended to be asking for the probability that there is at least one occurrence of consecutive heads of length $\geq 5.$  Under this interpretation, I disagree.

Comment: I wrote: **Expected number**

Comment: But @JMoravitz is there any way in which I could exploit linearity of expectations and thus the result obtained as the expected number to calculate the probability?

Comment: True, so JMoravitz' interpretation reasonable.  However, it isn't that implausible that a math student new to Probability might have used the same syntax and still have intended the alternate question.  You see a lot of interesting *wordings* re Probability questions presented on mathSE.

Comment: As far as the question in your last comment goes, that one is very interesting.  If I was trying to tackle it, I would calculate the probability of at least one occurrence of a string of 5 or more consecutive heads (from scratch).  Then, I would try to reverse-engineer some way of reaching the same math manipulations using the math in the linearity of expectations as a starting point.  And *better you than me*.

Comment: "*Is there any way in which I could exploit linearity of expectations... to calculate the probability (of at least one string of consecutive heads)?*"  For a problem such as this?  No.  However, there do exist other problems where it might be useful.  See [The Probabilistic Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method).